# Why would Tabulator Column Headings not show? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

I have a table on my react website using Tabulator. For some reason, the column headings would not show even though I have all the titles setup. My guess is that maybe cause I am setting the data again on componentDidUpdate() which is loading the data from redux.
Please help me on how to fix this.
The attached screenshot below shows how it is currently looking. I would want the column headings like "Name, ID" be shown on top.
[image: The fourth col is scribbled to hide emails]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {withRouter} from "react-router";
import 'react-tabulator/lib/styles.css'; // required styles
import 'react-tabulator/lib/css/tabulator_modern.css'; // theme
import Tabulator from "tabulator-tables";


class AllCoursesTabulator extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.el = React.createRef();
        this.tabulator = null;
        this.ref = null;

        this.dataEditedFunc = this.dataEditedFunc.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        let columns = [
            {title: "ID", width: 150, field: "course_id"},
            {title: "Name", field: "course_name"},
            {title: "Section", field: "course_section"},
            {title: "Instructor ID", field: "employee_id"},
            {title: "Instructor Email", field: "employee_email", width: 250},
            {
                title: "Ilearn Video Service Requested",
                field: "ilearn_video_service_requested",
                hozAlign: "center",
                formatter: "tickCross"
            },
            {title: "Ilearn Page ID", field: "ilearn_id"}

        ];

        this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.el, {
            columns: columns,
            layout: "fitColumns",
            data: this.props.data,
            reactiveData: true,
            height: "500px",
            cellEdited: this.dataEditedFunc
        })


    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {

        this.tabulator.replaceData(this.props.data)
    }

    dataEditedFunc(cellData) {
        //this function is to edit the cell on click
    };


    render() {

        return (

            <div className="emailTabulatorContainer">
                <div ref={el => (this.el = el)}/>
            </div>

        )
    }


}

function mapStateToProps({
                             globalsReducer,
                             coursesReducer
                         }, {props}) {

    let data = []
    let columns = []


    let formatData = (course) => {


        let ilearn_data = course.ilearn_page_id
        if (ilearn_data != null) {


            return {
                course_id: course.course_gen_id,
                course_name: course.course_name,
                course_section: course.course_section,
                employee_id: course.employee_id,
                employee_email: course.course_instructor.employee_email,
                ilearn_video_service_requested: course.ilearn_video_service_requested,
                ilearn_id: course.ilearn_page_id.ilearn_page_id

            }
        }
    }

    if (coursesReducer !== undefined) {
        Object.keys(coursesReducer).forEach(function (key) {
            data.push(formatData(coursesReducer[key]))
        });


    }
    return {
        data,
        columns,
        semester: globalsReducer['currentSemester'],
        coursesReducer
    }
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AllCoursesTabulator))
```

Please tell me how to fix this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify css?  Just Like this

```
.tabulator-header .tabulator-headers.tabulator-col {
     height: 40px !important;  }
```

But, that's not a good solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).